# How to determine Django version of a given code?

Tags: python, django

I have a site in Django. How to know (by watching at code), which version of Django it requires and which Python it requires?

Comment: That is close to impossible to do effectively. You can take a look at the release notes (for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.2/) about functions that have been removed: if these functions are still present, you know that they did not migrate to that version.

Comment: If there's a `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` in the project they might tell you which Django version was used.

Comment: any chance to find `requirements` file? -))

Comment: If the project is in version control, then you could look at the date of the most recent commits. For example, if the last commit was in January 2019, then it probably requires Django < 2.2, because Django 2.2 [was released](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.2/) in March 2019.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to guess the Django version. Normally if a proper requirements file (like `requirements.txt`) is added, this file specifies the version, for example:

```
# requirements.txt
Django==3.1
```

If that is not present, then you will need to look at the functions that are used. You can take a look at the release notes to see what functions have been removed. If your program uses a function *X*, and that function has been *removed* (not deprecated), then we know that the version will be older than that version.

For example if we look at the [release notes of Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id1), we see:

> The compatibility import of `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist` in `django.db.models.fields` is removed.

If your code thus contains a line:

```
from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
```

then this means that your project can not work with [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), since otherwise it would produce an error. You can also look for features introduced in that version and look if these are used. If that is the case, you know that the Django version is at least 3.1. You can perform *binary search* on the Django versions to easily find out the Django version. But often a project does not require a specific version, but can work with a *range* of versions, because the project simply does not depend on some of the new features.

You can do the same with the release notes of Python. For example if we look at [*What's New In Python 3.8*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-8), then we see:

> There is new syntax `:=` that assigns values to variables as part of a larger expression. It is affectionately known as "the walrus operator" due to its resemblance to the eyes and tusks of a walrus.

This thus means that if your code contains the walrus operator, then you know that this is at least [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8).